# Does the definition of limit correspond to the intuitive notion?

Tags: real-analysis, definitions

I have been pondering the question of whether the formal definition of limit captures well our intuitive notion of it now for the past few days, with no headway at all. Perhaps I could find some resolutions here.

It is well known that if for every $\epsilon>0$ there is some $\delta>0$ such that whenever $|x-x_0|<\delta$ then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$ then we say that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=L.$

My question concerns whether this definition captures the intuitive idea of $f(x)$ approaching $L$ as $x$ approaches $x_0.$ Precisely,

(i) Although it is not explicit in the formal definition that $\delta$ is arbitrary, but can it be shown that whenever $\delta$ exists according to the definition then it is arbitrary? In particular can it be shown that there is no lower (positive) bound on $\delta$ for every $\epsilon>0$?

(ii) Apart from this, can it be shown that $\epsilon$ becomes arbitrarily small as $\delta$ becomes arbitrarily small (obviously, this depends upon the truth of the claim in (i) above)? That is, is the dependence of $\delta$ on $\epsilon$ (or vice versa) such that $\epsilon\to 0$ as $\delta\to 0,$ for want of a better way of stating this? In fact, this would seem to be the original problem the former definition was designed to rectify, namely to make these intuitions of "arbitrarily getting near to" precise. In that case, has this been accomplished if it is not explicit from the definition that it accurately captures the intuition? Or, despite being able to frame the question otherwise, can it indeed be shown that the tendency of $\delta$ to $0$ forces $\epsilon$ to $0$? Otherwise what shall we say?

Many thanks.

Comment: May I suggest the **wonderful** series of video by 3blue1brown on [Essence of calculus](https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLZHQObOWTQDMsr9K-rj53DwVRMYO3t5Yr)? The 7-th one is about limits, but I recommend the whole series from its beginning.

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that *Yes, it captures the intuitive understanding of $f(x)\to L$ if $x\to x_0$* (except that technically one requires $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ rather than $|x-x_0|<\delta$ unless you’re expecting $f$ to be possibly continuous at $x_0$); however, for the enumerated questions (which probably you seek answers to better understand your main question),

(i) No, $\delta$ is not arbitrary but the supremum of all possible values of $\delta$ is *dependent* on $\epsilon$; the statement *“such that whenever $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$*” simply means that $|x-x_0|$ can be *arbitrarily smaller than* $\delta$——and I suppose this is what you mean when you ask “... $\delta$ is arbitrary?” The very construct of the definition does not demand any lower positive bound on $\delta$——in fact, the infimum or all possible values of $\delta$ is $0$ itself.

(ii) No, one **does not need** to show that $\epsilon$ becomes arbitrarily small as $\delta$ becomes arbitrarily small, and it can be to the contrary even in some case. To better see this, take the function
$$f(x)=
\left\lbrace
\begin{array}{ll}
0&\mbox{if $x\ne 0$}\\
1&\mbox{if $x=0$}
\end{array}
\right.
$$
It is immediately clear that “*for every $\epsilon>0$ and **any** $\delta>0$, we have that $|f(x)-0|<\epsilon$ whenever $0<|x-0|<\delta$*”; thus, by the definition, we have that $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$. Clearly, in this particular case, **any** positively-valued $\delta$ (as a function of $\epsilon$) works——that is, for each $\epsilon$, the supremum of all ‘satisfiable’ values of $\delta$ is $\infty$; thus, if you take $\delta:=2^{-\epsilon}$ say, then obviously $\epsilon\to\infty$ as $\delta\to 0$.

Comment: I think my main question is the one labelled (i). Thanks for your response, but I might not have phrased the question well. The force of the definition is that for any $\epsilon>0$ *no matter how small* we can find some $\delta=\delta(\epsilon)$ so that the inequality in $\epsilon$ is satisfied whenever the one in $\delta$ is. Now my question is, clearly, $\epsilon$ is assumed to be approaching $0$ here. But $\delta$ is not, as our intuition suggests it to be since we want to capture the idea that $x\to x_0.$ Can this in fact be shown from the definition itself?

Comment: Our intuition is **not** to suggest that $\delta\to 0$; rather, our intuition is that $x\to x_0$, which is captured by the expression $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$——to wit, $|x-x_0|$ can be _arbitrarily_ small as we please _as long as_ the “arbitrariness” is no more than $\delta$.

Comment: OK. Then in that way of thinking of it I suppose my question is: Can we show that $|x-x_0|$ *is* in fact arbitrarily small as $\epsilon$ becomes arbitrarily small? This possibility is only left open by the formal definition, but yet our intuition *requires* it always. Can it be shown to always be true?

Comment: **As long as $\delta$ exists**, then $|x-x_0|$ can be arbitrarily small; it is for that reason that the language of the definition says that **there exists $\delta>0$ ...**. You can think of it as saying $|x-x_0|$ takes **arbitrarily any** value between $0$ and $\delta$, hence it can take any value **arbitrarily close to $0$**. If no such $\delta$ existed for some $\epsilon$, that would be equivalent to saying that $|x-x_0|$ does not exist too. $$ \,.$$ Finally, as I explained with my example in the answer above, we don’t need to show that $|x-x_0|\to 0 $ is arbitrarily as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: Perhaps let's forget about $\epsilon$'s and $\delta$'s and whatnots for now. Suppose we have successfully bounded a quantity $Q$ such that $$0<Q<M,$$ are you saying that we can *guarantee* that $Q\to 0$ even if we do not *force* $M$ to be arbitrarily small?

Comment: If the language says that **there exists $M$** such that **whenever $0<Q<M$**......, then **YES**, we can guarantee that $Q\to 0$ even if we do not _force_ $M$ to be arbitrarily small ($Q$ can be arbitrarily _anything_ lying in the open interval $(0,M)$ and $Q\to 0$ is only one aspect; we can also even have $Q\to \frac{1}{2}M$ or $Q\to M$.). $$\,$$ If the language were rather to say **there exists $Q$** such that **whenever $0<Q<M$**.....then that would’ve been a different story.

Comment: If $Q$ can approach $0$ regardless of whether or not $M$ does, then what's the point of $M$?

Comment: If no (positive) $M$ can be found (which is equivalent to $M=0$), then $Q$ cannot exist (because the interval will reduce to $0<Q<0$) $$\,$$ You’d have to understand that the significance of the limit definition is not regarding $x\to x_0$ per se but regarding whether we can find **any deleted neighborhood** about $x_0$ whose values for $f$ are **arbitrarily close** to $L$. The “any deleted neighborhood” becomes $(x_0-\delta\,,x_0+\delta)\setminus\{x_0\}$ or equivalently $0<|x-x_0|<\delta$ and “arbitrarily close to $L$” becomes $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: The question is simple. Assume $Q$ exists, and that $M$ also exists, and $0<Q<M.$ Furthermore assume that we want to show that $Q\to 0.$ How do we do this if we insist that $M$ does **not** go to $0$?

Comment: So to be precise, if you are **only** assuming that $Q$ exists and $M$ also exists such that $0<Q<M$, then you can **only** show that $Q\to 0$ if $M\to 0$ (If that’s what you need an answer to, then that’s it). But that is not relevant to the limit definition because for the limit definition we are not saying $Q$ should exist, rather (only) $M$ should exist and a certain inequality relating $L$ should be satisfied for **every** $Q$ where $0<Q<M$.